# Why doesn't the distance scale on my Yongnuo flash properly change with aperture?

Tags: flash, yongnuo, guide-number

My Yongnuo  YN600EX-RT has a distance scale that is not working properly.

For example, with flash in manual mode, ISO100, 35mm, Power 1/1, GN=128 ft:

- The LCD display gives 10ft for both F8 and F11 when should be 16 ft and 11.5 ft.
- Likewise, it gives 5.5 ft for both F16 and F22 when it should be 8 ft and 5.8 ft.

Using GN = F# × distance one can calculate the distance for any F Stop.

A small difference between my calculated and flash calculated value might be OK, but obviously the distance should not be the same at a full stop apart.   Did I get a lemon or are others experiencing this too?  Is this a known problem with an available fix?

Comment: What lens are you using? Is it always at the same focal length when you check the distance on the flash? WHat is the zoom setting on the flash?

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 of these flashes and have not experienced this problem. Only thing I can suggest is maybe downloading and installing the YN flash firmware update. Maybe try to "reset" the flash and start over from the beginning.